# Strange timing behaviour

Tags: cron, slackware, virtualmin

I need to run a CRON each 5 minutes for a specific user `example.com`, the script executed is a php file.

File : /var/spool/cron/crontabs/example.com

```
/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/example.com/public_html/cron.php
```

Nothing happens (no error in log, no error mail, nothing). Same when testing with :

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/example.com/public_html/cron.php
```

Of course running the file manually works. Also, changing the CRON every minutes works :

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/example.com/public_html/cron.php
```

When trying the same start timing (5 minutes) but as `root`, it is running perfectly (/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root instead of /var/spool/cron/crontabs/example.com).

I've tested on Slackware 12.0 and Slackware 14.0... same problem.

Comment: Are you installing the new crontab with `crontab -e` which checks the format for problems?  Or, are you accessing the file directly with you editor?

Comment: @John1024 file editing with `vi` or with `webmin` (tested both). Also tested `crontab -u example.com -e`... no more luck.

Comment: If this command is the last line in the crontab file and it has no carriage return at the end it will not run. This is just a shot in the dark but I have had it happen in the past and spent hours trying to figure out the problem and all it was, was I didn't hit ENTER at the end of the line. Weird I know but it happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

`crontab -e` tells me that this is an error ("bad minute...
errors in crontab file, can't install"):

```
/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php
```

On the other hand, it accepts and runs the program every 5 minutes:

```
0-59/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php
```

This is also accepted and the program runs every 5 minutes:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /usr/bin/php
```

#### How to use `crontab -e`

`crontab -e` will open current crontab using the editor specified by the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables, if one exists, or `/usr/bin/editor` is neither exists.  After editing but before installing the revised file, it checks the format and, if problems are found, issues errors and offers to let you either re-edit the file or quit leaving crontab unchanged.

#### Common problems with cron

A community wiki with much information on common problems with `cron` is:

- [Reasons why crontab does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work)

Comment: Well I probably made a mistake with `/5` but I ommited to say that I tested `*/5` also. The point is that `0,5,10,...` is valid, but ONLY working if used in the root file (so runned as root). When used in the website user file, it will work one or two times and nothing else...

Comment: They run fine for me as a normal user.  What cron-related messages do you see in `/var/log` for messages?  Do you have cron set up to send email in case of errors?

Comment: It is configured to send email in case of error, but not email error nor logged error (/var/log/cron is empty).

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie  OK.  If the log files have no info and the email system fails, we need to work harder.  Try redirecting the stdout and stderr like this: `0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/example.com/public_html/cron.php >$HOME/my.log 2>&1`.  Also, as long as it is not working, use _only_ `crontab -e` to make changes to a crontab.